# Как решить конфликт версий node js и npm на сервере (удаленно)

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

На сервере установлена версия **node js 10.24.1**. Также там раньше использовалась версия **npm 6.14.12**. На данный момент версия npm обновилась до **9.6.6** и не может быть использована с указанной выше версией node js. Соответственно при попытке использования команды npm выбрасывает ошибки:

```
ERROR: npm v9.6.6 is known not to run on Node.js v10.24.1.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
ERROR: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exit-handler.js:19
const hasLoadedNpm = npm?.config.loaded
```

У меня есть только удаленный доступ к данному серверу. На сервере не установлен nvm, чтобы можно было через него каким либо образом обновить node js или переключить npm.

Я пробовала удаленно установить nvm с помощью команды

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash
```

Однако вот что получила на выходе

```
%Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15916  100 15916    0     0  88157      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 88422
=> Downloading nvm from git to '/root/.nvm'
=> Cloning into '/root/.nvm'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 360, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (360/360), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (306/306), done.
remote: Total 360 (delta 40), reused 170 (delta 28), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (360/360), 219.95 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (40/40), done.
* (detached from FETCH_HEAD)
master
=> Compressing and cleaning up git repository
=> Appending nvm source string to /root/.bashrc
=> Appending bash_completion source string to /root/.bashrc

ERROR: npm v9.6.6 is known not to run on Node.js v10.24.1.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

ERROR: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exit-handler.js:19
const hasLoadedNpm = npm?.config.loaded
                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
  at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
  at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:42:23)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:2:25)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm 
bash_completion
```

Команда nvm все также не работает.
Есть ли какая либо возможность решить данный момент? Буду признательна за советы по решению данного вопроса!

*Правка #1*

На данный момент у меня получилось на сервере установить nvm. Видимо его получилось все таки установить с помощью команды, которую я вставляла выше. Однако увидела я это только после нескольких авторизаций в системе и несколько раз пришлось запускать терминал.
Я установила по дефолту **node js 18.16.0**. Однако при вводе команды nvm list выводит такую информацию.

```
nvm list

   v18.16.0
     system
default -> 18.16.0 (-> v18.16.0)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v18.16.0) (default)
stable -> 18.16 (-> v18.16.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/hydrogen (-> v18.16.0)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.3 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.20.0 (-> N/A)
lts/hydrogen -> v18.16.0
```

Также при проверке с помощью команды node -v получается следующее:

```
node -v
node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by node)
```

*Правка 2*

На данный момент пришлось перейти на node v16.18.1. Но я вижу, что выбрана она только когда захожу на сервер под root правами. Если же я удаленно захожу в проект (а делаю я это под другим юзером), то вижу, что там все также установлена та же версия 10.24.1.

Comment: `npm install -g npm@6.14.12`

Comment: @DiMithras, к сожалению при использовании данной команды выплывает та же ошибка, т.к. npm не совместим с действующей версией node js

Comment: А через менеджер пакетов никак не установить? `apt` / `aptitude`?

Comment: @DiMithras, все таки получилось установить nvm, но это пока не решило мою проблему.

Comment: npm является модулем node.js, и идет в составе дистрибутива node.js. с тем старьем (node и npm), что у вас, вряд ли проекты будут собираться. вот тут [инструкция](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions), как обновлять/удалять/устанавливать

Comment: @АлексейОбухов, благодарю за отправленный материал. Я попробую решить данный вопрос этим способом